# Can't install Visual Studio 2014 CTP on Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I try and install Visual Studio 2014 CTP on Windows 8.1 I get the following error:

[image]

"This version of Visual STudio requires the April 2014 update to Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 Known as KB2919355. Please install KB 2919355 before you install Visual Studio on these operating systems".

To try and resolve I have checked both for new Windows updates and installed Windows updates and the KB2919355 does not appear on either list.

My next port of call was to manually download the update from Microsoft however when I try and run it I get the error message "The update is not applicable to your computer".  Which is confusing considering I've just been told to install it by the Visual Studio installer.

I checked the eventlog and the WUSA.exe gave the following error message: "Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2149842967 "" (Command line: "C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe  C:\Users\kevin\Downloads\Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu")".

I have tried searching for the error code 2149842967 but all of the solutions say to run the Microsoft fixit application which I've tried but to no avail.

Comment: As noted on the support page for [KB 2919355](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355), you need to have [KB 2919442](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919442) installed first. Note that KB 2919355 is a mandatory update for Windows 8.1 and all future updates require it including the latest rollup [KB 3000850](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000850).

Comment: Same problem and same solution to Visual Studio 2015 preview

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found your question when i was trying to solve this problem and i tried to install using Microsoft download center and i got the message "The update is not applicable to your computer" then tried to get other updates from windows update and install about 40-45 updates then i checked again for any availabe update then three update show up and last of them was KB2919355.Finally i could install Visual Studio 2015. **KB2919355** requires **2919442**.Before earlier updates installed some updates cannot be installed.You should check available updates even if it says there is no update.Just check after each restart.Finally you can get it.

Comment: I've finally sorted this by manually installing package 2919442 like you said. Unfortunately I couldnt use the automatic updates feature as this is a work machine and updates are control by the domain administrator.  Installing 2919442 did allow me to install 2919355 which then allowed me to install Visual Studio.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 8.1, if you want install:
+ Visual Studio 2013 community edition
+ Visual Studio 2015 preview

Download and install step by step:
with Windows 8.1 x64:

1. Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu
2. Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu
3. Windows8.1-KB2932046-x64.msu
4. Windows8.1-KB2934018-x64.msu
5. Windows8.1-KB2937592-x64.msu
6. Windows8.1-KB2938439-x64.msu
7. Windows8.1-KB2959977-x64.msu

And have an exist simple solution, **update Windows to lastest version**, using **Windows Update**.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Server 2012 r2 the process for fixing is the same as above. Tho I did find it hard to find all the required updates (before running KB2919355-x64). After running Windows update and installing 41 updates (KB2919442 was one item included)

I have been able to install fine!

Comment: This also was necessary while trying to use TFS 2015 vNext build's "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" step, though I had to manually install  KB2919442 before 2919355 showed up in windows update. It was reporting ''The return code -2147205120 was not expected during installation of Test Agent'